# No of mappers which run for a pig job d

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Q1- Does number of mappers which are run for a pig job only depend on the number of input splits?
Q2: Does the number of mappers depend on the statements which we use in the pig script. eg, foreach, group, join, filter? If I have 128 mb of input file will it run only one mapper irrespective of the statements which i have used in pig.
Q3: when does combiner run for pig?

Q4: In which scenario combiner runs multiple times in a map reduce job?

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Yes and no, Yes the number of mapper run in any stage depends on numbers of input splits. But there is no guarantee that there is going to be only one stage.Thus a total number of mappers in the execution of any query actually depends on the query itself which also answer your 2 question (Q2).

Let's take an example suppose you have a dataset which contains the population of 50 countries in a single input slpit and you need to write a query such that you want the name of countries which have 3, 4 and 5 largest population but they should appear in reverse order which means 5 most populated country should appear first followed by 4 and so on.  Now when you write a query for it in pig, map reduce jobs might run in the following way to give a result.

The first map reduce job will sort countries in descending order then saved the result.Now on the first map reduce result will run the second map reduce where it will select 3, 4 and 5 most populated country and save it.Then on the result of second map reduce it ran the third map reduce job and again sorted them in desired order and displayed the final result.Major take away from this example is even though there was a single input split but the number of mapper ran was 3 . (The approach I had to take to solve this example is very naive and there are possible ways to do all these tasks in single map reduce job and I am quite confident such query in pig will take single MR job. but here point is to get a perspective about how pig query might run that is why I ran 3 maps reduce job. )

Q3 and Q4 also have a similar answer like 1 and 2 it all depends on your query.Unless you have defined some constraint for combiner explicitly.

But I am sure map reduce programs written by developers for these queries are optimized such that they consume least resources.